# How to calculate feedback \$\beta\$ in two common-source stages feedback

Tags: feedback

The following is from the book *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 307.

[image]

KCL at node F.

$$ (V_{in} - V_F) g_{m1} + \frac{V_{out} - V_F} {R_F} = \frac{V_F} {R_S}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_F = \frac{V_{in} g_{m1} + V_{out} / R_F} {g_{m1} + 1/R_F + 1/R_S}$$

$$\Rightarrow \beta = \frac{1 / R_F} {g_{m1} + 1/R_F + 1/R_S} = \frac{R_S} {g_{m1} R_F R_S + R_F + R_S}$$

However, the book said this

$$\beta = \frac{R_S} {R_F + R_S}$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the model.
Check Figure 8.51 for the G model. \$ \beta = g_{21} \$, and you can see why the book calculated \$ \beta \$ that way.

Comment: @internet but You write similar  formula as mine under comment of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/701003/what-is-the-feedback-beta-for-this-resistor-feedback

Comment: They could be different depending on how you model it.

Comment: @interent Could you please explain why you write this equation at the beginning?

Comment: \$ g_{21}\$ is open circuit voltage ratio so the formula in the book is correct.

Comment: @internet Could you please point out where my equation is incorrect?

Comment: I haven't looked at your equation in detail, but the issue is not that your equation is incorrect. You need to consider the model; beta values of different models are not necessarily the same.
Razavi explained it himself somewhere on YouTube if I rememeber it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Figure 8.51 in the book, you can see that the author modeled the feedback network as G parameters, as in the images below (all taken from the  book by Razavi above).

[image]

[image]

The feedback factor \$ \beta \$ in this model is equal to \$ g_{21} \$:
$$
g_{21} = \frac{V_2}{V_1}\bigg|_{I_2=0}
$$
In this case, \$ g_{21} = V_F/V_{out} \$ when there is no current from the MOSFET.
$$\beta = g_{21} =  \frac{R_S} {R_F + R_S}$$
[image]

Comment: What's two port network in this cmos circuit here? Can you mark them in the box? Do you mean \$I_1 = I_S = I_F \$